# static constexpr function work in template struct but not struct. Why?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

The following compiles:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/binary/binary.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <int dummy=0>
struct S {
  static constexpr auto get_parse_rule() {
    return x3::byte_ >> x3::byte_;
  }
};

int main() {
  auto parse_rule = S<>::get_parse_rule();
  return 0;
}
```

But this does not:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/binary/binary.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct S {
  static constexpr auto get_parse_rule() {
    return x3::byte_ >> x3::byte_;
  }
};

int main() {
  auto parse_rule = S::get_parse_rule();
  return 0;
}
```

When I read both pieces I see the same thing, but apparently they're not the same. Can someone enlighten me on why this is?

Comment: Can you add the error you get?

Comment: Why do you think that the latter does not work?

Comment: Some errors are more difficult to diagnose in template class/function. and some errors can only be diagnosed when template is instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constexpr function's return type must be a [LiteralType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). The boost spirit returns something that isn't fulfilling those requirements. Constexpr funcion template instantiation may compile when it does not fulfill the requirements but you won't get compile time constants from it anyway.

Comment: Apparently I shouldn't even be able to use constexpr. From cppreference.com: "Explicit instantiation of a function template or of a member function of a class template cannot use inline or constexpr.".